# Drawing Alphabets (using bezier curves) with my finger in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, bezier

I'm trying how to Generate Alphabets using Bezier Curves in iOS based on user input. Are there any existing classes for this? Can someone give me a general summary of what would be required? I just need help getting started.

Comment: you want to draw alphabet using bezier curve?

Comment: Yes i want to draw alphabets using bezier Curve.

Comment: letme guess you want to make an application in which user draws using touch and you convert it to text in short ICR image charector recognition?

Comment: Yes , That's What i Want..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this tutorial may be this will help you...
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_freehand-drawing/

Comment: it's ok. But How to recognize that Alphabet?